# Div elements overlapping in tailwind css

Tags: html, tailwind-css

I am trying to create logo carousel using html and tailwind css. But when I'm doing this logo images are overlapping.

Suggest me a way to create logo carousel

Here is my html code

```
<div class="clients pt-12 w-screen overflow-hidden inline-flex">      
<div class="logo-slider inline-flex">
<img src="image1" alt="">
<img src="image2"  alt="">
<img src="image3"  alt="">
<img src="image4"  alt="">
<img src="image5" alt="">
<img src="image6" alt="">  

</div>

     
<div class="logo-slider inline-flex">
<img src="image1" alt="">
<img src="image2"  alt="">
<img src="image3"  alt="">
<img src="image4"  alt="">
<img src="image5" alt="">
<img src="image6" alt="">  

</div>
</div>
```

here is my css code

```
@keyframes slide {
from {
transform: translateX(0);
}
to {
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
}


.logo-slider{  
animation: 20s slide infinite linear;
}
.logo-slider img{
margin: 0 50px;
height: 70px;
}
```